# Should there be a preposition "of" between these words?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The text is:

"It’s an expected move that comes as states have broadened access on their own and expands the number eligible by tens of millions."

in the part: "the number eligible" should it be: "the number OF eligible"?

Comment: Because the "that-clause" before ***and*** is so long, I'd say the cited text hasn't been properly proof-read. Personally I think it would be *much* easier to parse if the writer had included *[comma] **that*** before ***expands***. Also, for no reason I can put my finger on, I think ***which*** is a much better "relativiser" here than ***that*** if it's going to be repeated (but I have no particular preference if the relativiser occurs only once).

Comment: The bracketing is: _[It’s an expected move that [comes as states have broadened access on their own] and [expands the number eligible by tens of millions]_. It sounds clumsy because there is a coordination of two head clauses with the single marker "that".

Answer (score 2):

The complete sentence is actually actually

> It’s an expected move that comes as states have broadened access on their own and expands the number [that are] eligible by tens of millions

It is permissible to omit **that are** from this sentence using [whiz-deletion](http://wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=24650).

Comment: I very much dislike the term 'whiz-deletion' since it implies that "eligible" is some kind of (hybrid?) relative clause, which it isn't. In the NP "the number eligible", "eligible" is an AdjP postmodifying the noun "number". Not everything that postmodifies a noun is a relative clause, either full or 'reduced'.

Answer (score 1):

No. *eligible* is an adjective, and while it is occasionally used as a noun ("the eligible") it is rare. In particular the construction "the number of eligible" is extremely rare.

The construction here is that *eligible* is an adjective which follows its noun ("number"). I'm not exactly sure why this is grammatical in this case (mostly adjectives precede their head nouns in English), but I note that it is a frequent pattern with quantities:

> The number available

> The quantity left

> The proportion vaccinated

> The amount wasted

In most of these examples the adjective is a participle, but not in all.